# MKDIR_P isn't defined in Makefile

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf

I have a customer's site that is failing to install. The root of the problem is that the variable MKDIR_P is never expanded. After looking around, it appears that this is a tricky problem that rears its head in different versions of autotools, although this site has autoconf 2.69, and none of the sample problems (and solutions) I could find were with versions that recent. Does anyone out there know how to write a solution that is portable or at least somewhat portable with respect to different versions of autotools?

Comment: The version of autoconf at the site is irrelevant unless you are shipping broken tarballs.   If you ship properly built tarballs there is no problem with different versions of the autotools because they only ones that matter are the ones on your development box.

Comment: This site has a problem with our tarball and needs to regenerate things. Our tarballs work at every other site.

Comment: Is there a config.site file in $prefix/share?  Is CONFIG_SITE set when you run configure?

Comment: CONFIG_SITE is not set when I configure. There is a config.site file on the system (I found one using locate) but it is not in $prefix/share.

Comment: Are the makefiles generated using Automake, or are they manually maintained?

Comment: They are generated by automake and the configure script. In other words, they are generated in standard autotools fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is a bug in the version of automake that ships with SLES 11 SP2 (1.10.1). Downgrading automake solved the problem although I don't remember what version the site went to. The problem doesn't continue into later versions of automake, so upgrading further should also solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This should not be necessary, but you should be able to simply define it at configure time:

```
./configure MKDIR_P='mkdir -p'
```

Comment: This did not work on their system. Other things that haven't worked include adding AC_PROG_MKDIR_P to configure.ac and adding MKDIR_P="mkdir -p" AC_SUBST(MKDIR_P) to configure.ac. Does this mean that their autotools installation is just complete garbage?

Comment: It doesn't result in MKDIR_P being defined in the Makefile.

Comment: Do you mean the line `MKDIR_P = @MKDIR_P@` does not appear in `Makefile.in`, or that `MKDIR_P =` appears in Makefile with nothing after the `=`, or that `grep MKDIR_P Makefile` fails, or something else?  Is `MKDIR_P` defined in `config.status`?

Comment: It is correctly defined in config.status, but it is not in Makefile.in nor is it in Makefile. The only place it appears in the Makefile is mkdir_p = $(MKDIR_P), but there is no definition of MKDIR_P in the Makefile, not even an empty one.

Comment: @dbeer, then you need to add `MKDIR_P = @MKDIR_P@`

Comment: Apparently my bug was caused by SLES 11 SP2, which has a bug in automake. Downgrading automake solved the problem.